# How to use "*" in nodeName

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc, azure-automation

Say I have 2 roles in my DSC setup and I have variable amount of nodes in my setup:

```
$configdata = @{
    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName = "*Web*" # < problem lies here
                      # can be prodWeb## or devWeb##
            Role = "IIS", "basic"
        }
        @{
            NodeName = "*"
            Role = "basic"
        }
    )
}
```

DSC resource:

```
Configuration CFG
{   
    $AllNodes.where{ $_.Role.Contains("Basic") }.NodeName 
    {
    ...
    }

    $AllNodes.where{ $_.Role.Contains("IIS") }.NodeName 
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically what I've done is this:

```
Configuration Windows
{   
    node $allnodes.NodeName {
        switch ($Node.Role) {
            "Role1" {
                ...
            }
            "Role2" {
                ...
            }
            "Role3" {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My configuration data:

```
@{ AllNodes = @( @{ NodeName = "web"; Role = "Role1", "Role2" } ) }
```

And for another set of nodes:

```
@{ AllNodes = @( @{ NodeName = "other"; Role = "Role1", "Role3" } ) }
```

I'm using Azure Automation to assign configurations to nodes, so it doesn't check the node name, it just applies whatever roles the configuration had at compile time.

Comment: Still i have one doubt. Even i told you this solution. Could you pls help me in understanding how this switch helps you? If the role is having wildcard, then are you validating that in the switch case?

Comment: roles do not have wildcards, switch is just an easy way to apply all the configurations to the same node (if it has many roles). And solution you gave didn't help a bit @RanadipDutta

Comment: Fine. NO Issues. My understanding was different.

Answer (score 1):

The AllNodes entry in configuration data is an array of hashtables. Each hashtable needs to have a key NodeName. The value will get substituted when the expression evaluates. So a nodename like web* will not work

Comment: any real way to overcome that? I don't think that creating configuration data each time is a viable solution

Comment: You can script generation of the configuration data from your representation.